# adding x=y line to hexplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

Hi I am trying to look at different ways to visualize a dataset by using hexplots in ggplot. 
I essentially want a hexplot with
1. loess line
2. regression line
3.x=y line --> equivalent of abline(0,1)

So far I have come up with this kind of code:

```
c <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, wt))
c+stat_binhex()+stat_smooth(method="loess", colour="red")+stat_smooth(method='lm', se=FALSE, colour="orange")+ geom_abline(intercept=0, slope=1)
```

This gives the picture below, but I still do not see the x=y reference line. Please help. I'm not sure why it is not working. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The y=x reference line is not inside the coordinate ranges you plot. If you change to

```
geom_abline(slope=1, intercept=-15)
```

you will see your line on the plot.

Comment: It's still not an x=y line though. The line appears but it is not the reference line I need

Comment: Did you read my first sentence? y=x is outside of your plot's ranges.